# Проблема с удаления Virtualbox с компьютера

Tags: oracle, virtualbox, delete, удаление, windows-11

мне нужно удалить virtualbox с компьютера на windows 11 home, поскольку в virtualbox произошла ошибка, которую никак не получилось исправить, в итоге, я получил программу-кирпич, которую нельзя ни открыть, ни удалить, помимо этого, из-за того, что программу нельзя удалить, ее также нельзя и скачать.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я делаю так: Открываю редактор реестра и в поиске вбиваю название проги и удаляю все ссылки которые там будут найдены, лучше прогнать поиск пару раз, а дальше пробую переустановить прогу , если результат нулевой, прибегаю к помощи сторонних программ деинсталляторов